# How to create a filter to show issues without worklog in JIRA

Tags: jira, agile

I am using JIRA for tracking issues and I want to show Issues without worklogs using JQL.

Any answers is much accepted. Thanks!

Comment: In where, what language, what API?

Comment: @iJay JQL stands for JIRA Query Language

Comment: Try: timespent is empty

Comment: @Robert Fixed my issue. Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. I added the answer as well, you can mark it as answered.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this jql query:

Timespent is empty